# What script or program is needed to keep a unix system date correct?

Tags: linux, unix

What script or program is needed to keep a unix system date correct? I find that my linux servers are behind a few minutes from actual time.

Answer (score 15):

Use ntpd.

From [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpd):

> The ntpd daemon synchronizes the local clock to one or more remote NTP
>   servers, and can also act as an NTP server itself, redistributing the
>   local time.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [ntp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).  Here's some info for [installing and configuring it on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/NTP.html).

Answer (score 3):

We use **ntpdate** - which I think is a lot lighter weight than the full ntp.

I have a cron job that runs "ntpdate my.ntp.server > /dev/null" a couple times per day to keep things in sync.

If it is important that your time be adjusted gradually (rather than synched immediately), then **ntp** would be your better option.

Note that **if this is a virtual machine**, time drift is a common problem, and there might be some included "tools" that allow you to sync time with the host machine - usually a better option.

Comment: +1 for the mentioning of how this issue happens more on virtual machines.  I've used a service set to do this more regularly but cron obviously works great too.

Answer (score 2):

ntpd, as others have pointed out, is the obvious choice to keep the clock in sync once it's set. However, you'll probably also want "ntpdate" to set it initially from a good network time source, as ntp won't adjust the clock if it's more than a couple minutes out of sync.

Both should be available from the package manager of the Linux distro you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You would need the network time protocol deamon [link](http://www.ntp.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might try adjtime

Answer (score 0):

I`m using exactly this crontab entry.

```
*/10    *       *       *       *       root    /usr/sbin/ntpdate time.fu-berlin.de > /dev/null 2>&1
```

time.fu-berlin.de is a server in germany, you can use it also but I suggest using a timeserver nerer to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use ntp, which recommendation I would second (er, third; well, Nth), you will need a timeserver. If your organization does not have one, you can use [pool.ntp.org](http://www.pool.ntp.org/).